# Combinations with repetition in prolog that satisfy certain criteria

Tags: list, prolog, combinations, combinatorics

I'm trying to make a prolog program that generates all combinations (with repetition) of n elements from a list of m elements whose sum is between two given number `A` and `B`. I managed to make the program for permutations, but I hvae no idea what should I use for `rep_combinations`.

Here is the program for permutations:

```
chech(L,A,B):-
    findall([X1,X2,X3,X4 ], (
        member(X1, L),
        member(X2, L),
        member(X3, L),
        member(X4, L),
        Sum is X1+X2+X3+X4,
        Sum > A,
        Sum < B
    ), Solutions),
    write(Solutions)
.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the items (X1, X2, X3, X4) to form a combination and then get a set of said combinations. E.g:

```
 chech2(L,A,B):-
    setof(Combination, X1^X2^X3^X4^Sum^(
        member(X1, L),
        member(X2, L),
        member(X3, L),
        member(X4, L),
        Sum is X1+X2+X3+X4,
        Sum > A,
        Sum < B,
        msort([X1,X2,X3,X4 ], Combination)
    ), Solutions),
    write(Solutions).
```

I just changed the template used as a result of your `findall/3` to get the sorted permutation (using `msort/2`), and changed the `findall/3` to `setof/3` to remove duplicates.

Note that it is strange that you print the result instead of adding a fourth argument to your procedure to unify the result (and then the caller can print it if it likes to do so).

Comment: or you could simply add ordering constraints, like `member(X1,L), member(X2,L), X2 >= X1, member(X3,L), X3 >= X2, member(X4,L), X4 >= X3, ...` and remove `msort(...)` and it should be much faster, since you avoid unnecessary computation at the earliest time